# Не импортируется модуль TenserFlow

Tags: python, pycharm, импорт, tensorflow

Скачал через терминал tenserflow. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После скачивания , в PyCharm idea ввожу такие же строки ,и появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 37, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/x/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/HelloDigit!.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

**Почему** в консоле всё работает , а в пайчарме нет ?
**Как** как решить проблему так , что бы не вылазила ошибка ?

P.S. Версия python - 3.6

Comment: в PyCharm стоит интерпретатор тот же?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверьте в PyCharm путь к интерпретатору. Это можно сделать перейдя в `Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter`. 
Найденный путь сравните с результатом выполнения следующего кода в терминале:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Если они различные, укажите путь к интерпретатору из терминала в PyCharm

---

P.S. В разделе `Project Interpreter` сразу можно посмотреть установленные библиотеки.

Comment: Всё совпадает.Такая же проблема при установки dlib ...